# Is a pre-convert considered a Noahide?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, noachide-laws, noahidism, judaism

If a non-Jew [ex-Muslim] is working with the Beit Din for an Orthodox Conversion to Judaism, is he still considered to be a Noahide as he does not yet have a status of being Jewish?

Comment: With respect to what?

Comment: There is no conversion to "Noahide".  Noahides are self-proclaimed.  They simply state they obey the 7 Noahide laws.  However, to be recognized by Judaism as such, they must make a declaration before 3 judges.  See http://www.wikinoah.org/en/index.php/How_to_become_a_Noahite

Comment: Sorry I mean conversion to Judaism not Noahidism. If a non-Jew is in the process of converting to Judaism are they still considered a Noahide?

Comment: Considered Noahide by Jews?  Not automatically.  See my link above.

Comment: Yes, unless a person converts, they may be a Noahide.

Comment: A convert going through the conversion process is certainly expected to keep the 7 Noahide laws, yes! If you're asking whether such a person has a special status, the answer is complicated. Historically we did not perform the conversion process over months and years the way we do now, and so halachically a prospective convert was treated as 100% not a Jew prior to Brit milah/mikvah for the short time (around a week) they spent between deciding to convert and the actual conversion

Comment: Now that we require at least one year for the conversion process, things are done differently and in some respects people going through the conversion process are not treated as fully non Jews, see the answers to this question for example (all of them not just mine!) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133638/is-it-possible-to-have-non-jews-who-are-converting-or-non-jewish-relatives-ove/133639#133639

Answer (score 0):

Even in the most [extreme case of death](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/middle-east/woman-killed-in-oct-7-hamas-attacks-denied-jewish-burial-due-to-incomplete-judaism-conversion), prior to completing conversion, the candidate remains a Gentile.

The candidate today could be called Gentile or Noahide. I distinguish the terms, as do a lot of Noahides, but I don't actually think it makes any difference in Jewish law about the term. I'm unsure a candidate for conversion would refer to himself distinctly as a Noahide, though that might be technically correct. Usually, the term is for people who are living as Noahides. If Gentile who has never heard of a Noahide went to a rabbi who has never met a Noahide and asks to convert, I doubt the term would come up at all. As unflattering as it might sound, until you are a 'yid,' you are still a 'goy.'

However, I suspect that if Jewish law has historically called people who were in the conversion process "Noahides," a lot more Jews would know what a Noahide was by now.