# Can someone call himself Jewish if he is in the process of converting?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, beit-din-court, judaism

Shalom! If one is in the final stages of conversion to Orthodox Judaism, is not a Noahide,  does not belong to any religion, is it appropriate for him to say he is Jewish? He does not want to tell strangers about his conversion.

Comment: You should check with the rabbi overseeing your conversion process. We can't know the particulars of your situation or your community

Comment: How is this different from your other question? The title is different, but the question explanation is basically asking the same thing: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135669/is-a-pre-convert-considered-a-noahide. Did you not get your answer there? Maybe think about this: once you are engaged, should you go around telling everyone you are this woman's husband/ man's wife, or would it be more prudent to wait until after the chupa? As for your desire for privacy in the matter of conversion, please discuss this with your Dayanim, I'm sure they can offer better advice than we can

Comment: I'm not clear on the situation you are describing. Who are these "strangers" who are asking you your religion? No one ever asks me mine. Even if I needed to lie about it, I wouldn't need to, because the issue never comes up. - If you're talking about being counted in a minyan, then it's obvious that you mustn't deceive people who will think they have a minyan when they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Self-evidently, someone in the final stages of conversion to Orthodox Judaism is not yet a Jew. The [Gemoro Shabbos 55a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.55a.12?lang=bi) states that

> חותמו של הקדוש ברוך הוא אמת
>
> the seal of the Holy One Blessed be He is truth.

This potential convert wants to come under the tabernacle of HKB”H and in the process wishes to utter untruths.
No he must not utter untruths.